# Handle new line with sed in Unix

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, sed

I am converting `Testng` assertions to `AssertJ` I am using `sed` command for the same. I am hanged when there are statements with new line like,

*Exa 1:*

```
assertEquals(person.getAddressLine1(),
        "This is long line, so needs to go in second line as per Formatter.........!!!!!!!");
```

*Exa 2:*

```
assertEquals(person.getAddressLine1(),
             "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
                     "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
                     "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple");
```

**My current solution** : This is running perfect for single line assertions.

```
sed -i 's/assertEquals([[:blank:]]*\(.\+\),[[:blank:]]*\(["].\+["]\+\))[[:blank:]]*;/Assertions.assertThat(\1).isEqualTo(\2);/g'
```

**NOTE** : I know, I can change the maximum length of line in my editor Formatterr, but somehow I can't change it because then I need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> again, and that's not possible for me.

**UPDATED** : The expected output for both examples are given below.

*Exa 1:*

```
Assertions.assertThat(person.getAddressLine1()).isEqualTo("This is long line, so needs to go in second line as per Formatter.........!!!!!!!");
```

*Exa 2:*

```
Assertions.assertThat(person.getAddressLine1()).isEqualTo("This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
        "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
        "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple");
```

Comment: Are you willing to accept a solution where multiline assertions will be converted by `sed` into single-line statements?

Comment: Any regex based solution will run into errors when you have comma and double quote used inside the assertions e.g. `assertEquals("a \"quoted\" value, foo, bar", str);`

Comment: @Leon : Yes....

Comment: @anubhava : It's acceptable, that's why I have not given that example here.

Comment: I am willing to accept any solution which is applicable to above scenarios (number of lines may vary for second parameter).

Comment: ok, what's your expected output for both inputs shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can potentially do it but command will be more complex due to presence of newlines. Here is a simpler `perl` command using slurp mode to do the same:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\bassertEquals\(\s*([^,]+),\s*([^)]+)\)\s*;/Assertions.assertThat($1).isEqualTo($2);/' file
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JjwPA/2)

---

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
sed -i -E ':a;N;s/\n[ \t]*//g;s/;/;\n/;s/assertEquals\([[:blank:]]*([^,]+),[[:blank:]]*([^)]+)\)[[:blank:]]*;/Assertions.assertThat(\1).isEqualTo(\2);/;ba' file
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, but actually I needed it with sed.

Comment: thanks @anubhava, but you might have missed that I have already answered myself before you tried with `sed`

Comment: Ah just realized. You have extra `'{}' \;` in the end (probably from `find` command's `-exec` option)

Comment: One more problem I see in your sed is that it won't work with single line `assertEquals` e.g. `assertEquals(person.getAddressLine1(), "This is long line, so needs to go in second line as per Formatter.........!!!!!!!");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your kind support, I am finally able to do it with `sed` as per my requirement.

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/[[:blank:]]*assertEquals(\([^;]\+\),\(\n[[:blank:]]*\([^;]\+\(\n\)*\)\))[[:blank:]]*;/    Assertions.assertThat(\1).isEqualTo(\2);/g' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approximation to what you want that will work when the first argument to `assertEquals` is entirely on the first line and DOES NOT contain a comma:

```
sed -i 's/assertEquals(\s*\([^,]\+\),/Assertions.assertThat(\1).isEqualTo(/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've access to `awk`, this might also do

**Script**

```
awk '$0 ~ /assertEquals\(person.getAddressLine1\(\),/{
printf "Assertions.assertThat(person.getAddressLine1()).isEqualTo(";
getline;
gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*"/,"\"")}1' filename
```

**Sample Output**

```
Assertions.assertThat(person.getAddressLine1()).isEqualTo("This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
        "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple" +
        "This is very long line, so needs to break down in multiple");
```